# ¿Como mostrar datos de una url de cada cada personaje en una api con react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

quisiera saber si me podrían ayudar en algo, estoy trabajando en la api de Star Wars y debo hacer el llamado de los personajes y planetas, aparte de eso los detalles de cada uno hasta ahí todo esta bien lo que sucede es que dentro de cada personaje tiene los vehículos, las películas y las naves, como puedo estructurar para que no me aparezca el link si no la información que esta en el link.

Esta es la manera con la que llamo a la api:

```
import axios from "axios";

const todosPersonajes = async (state) => {
    const peticion = await axios.get(`https://swapi.dev/api/people`)
    state(peticion.data.results)
}
```

Este es el codigo donde llamo los detalles del personaje:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { FooterApp } from '../FooterApp/FooterApp';
import { NavbarApp } from '../NavbarApp/NavbarApp';
import { unicoPersonaje } from '../Hooks/FuncionesPerson';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FaReply } from 'react-icons/fa';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Personajes from '../Img/Personaje.jpg'
import '../Hooks/Detalles.css';

export const DetallePersonaje = () => {
  const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);

  const idByParams = useParams();
  const personaje = unicoPersonaje(idByParams.name);

  useEffect(() => { personaje.then(res => setData(res)) }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <NavbarApp />
      <button className='boton_atras'>
        <a href='../Personajes'> <FaReply size={30} /></a>
      </button>
      <div className='Detalles_person'>
        <div className='CardDetalle'>
          <Card style={{ width: '22rem' }}>
            <Card.Img src={Personajes} className='front' />
          </Card>
        </div>
        <div className='detalles'>
          <h6>Nombre: <span>{data.name}</span></h6>
          <h6>Altura: <span>{data.height}</span></h6>
          <h6>Masa: <span>{data.mass}</span></h6>
          <h6>Color de Pelo: <span>{data.hair_color}</span></h6>
          <h6>Color de Piel: <span>{data.skin_color}</span></h6>
          <h6>Color de Ojos: <span>{data.eye_color}</span></h6>
          <h6>Cumpleaños:  <span>{data.birth_year}</span></h6>
          <h6>Genero: <span>{data.gender}</span></h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className='tajetasdetalle'>
        <div>
          <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
            <Card.Text className='Card_Text'>N/A</Card.Text>
          </Card>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
            <Card.Text className='Card_Text'>N/A</Card.Text>
          </Card>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
            <Card.Text className='Card_Text'>N/A</Card.Text>
          </Card>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
            <Card.Text className='Card_Text'>N/A</Card.Text>
          </Card>
        </div>
      </div>
      <FooterApp />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Lo que dice N/A es donde quiero que vaya la informacion de las URL de las naves, vehiculos y peliculas.

Agradezco  de corazón la ayuda.

Comment: donde usas `todosPersonajes`? que hace `unicoPersonaje`?

Comment: UnicoPersonaje es una constante donde puedo hacer que en otra pagina diferente me muestre los datos de un solo ese personaje que es alli donde quiero que me muestre los datos de las naves, vehiculos y peliculas de un personaje sea cual sea este es el codigo de UnicoPersonaje:                                         const unicoPersonaje = async (id) => {
    const peticion = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/${id}/`)
    const data = peticion.json()
    return data
}

Comment: Como son varias urls... Como las quieres mostrar? Una seguida de la otra como texto, separadas por coma , un link <a> para cada uno de las urls? O como?

Comment: @Pipe osea que me pueda aparecer la información que contienen las URL ¿si me entiendes?

Comment: Si, se se puede... Lo que pregunto es como quieres mostrar esas url... Porque son varias... Se pueden solo mostrar la url como texto, mostrarun link para cada una, es decir hay muchas formas de mostrar una lista de urls... Como las quieres mostrar?

Comment: Enlistarlas osea que cuando yo le de en "Detalles" de cualquier personaje me muestre aparte de los detalles personales me muestre tambien los datos de las naves, vehiculos y en que peliculas aparece ese personaje,

Comment: @Pipe quiero es llamar la información que esta en las URL

Comment: Ah, si lo que quieres es mostrar la información de cada una de ellas, lo que debes hacer es un fetch por cada una de las urls... puedes consultarlas al tiempo, o puedes consultarla cada una por aparte... y apenas esté lista mostrarla. Pero el código para eso es demasiado extenso... y no tengo tiempo de ayudarte.